# How to populate dropdown box with global binding in Adobe LiveCycle

Tags: drop-down-menu, adobe, livecycle-designer

Below is my XML data which i want to populate in drop down list in Adobe LiveCycle Designer:
I have a dropdown list in a fragment in Adobe LiveCycle. I want to use bind the data using data binding: use global data with it. How can i do it?

Here is my XML Data:
`<CourtDetails_of_the_Applicant>
    <CourtDetails><br/>
         <court_id>1</court_id>
         <nameofcourt>Superior Court of Justice</nameofcourt>
     </CourtDetails>
     <CourtDetails>
          <court_id>2</court_id>
          <nameofcourt>Civil Superioir Court of Justice</nameofcourt>
      </CourtDetails>
</CourtDetails_of_the_Applicant>`

What values should put in **name and items field**:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUwLK.png

Comment: Please add some of the code you have tried.

Comment: Below is my XML data which i want to populate in drop down list in Adobe LiveCycle Designer:    
`<CourtDetails_of_the_Applicant>
    <CourtDetails><br/>
         <court_id>1</court_id>
         <nameofcourt>Superior Court of Justice</nameofcourt>
     </CourtDetails>
     <CourtDetails>
          <court_id>2</court_id>
          <nameofcourt>Civil Superioir Court of Justice</nameofcourt>
      </CourtDetails>
</CourtDetails_of_the_Applicant>`

What values should put in **name and items field**:
![enter image description here][1]

  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/uUwLK.png

Comment: Sorry i am new to stackoverflow please see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22711336/2361132